# ¿Por qué las listas infinitas no cierran en Haskell?

Tags: haskell

Estoy aprendiendo Haskell. Quisiera saber por qué:

```
filter (< 40) $ map (^3) [1..]
```

Devuelve una lista abierta, mientras que por ejemplo:

```
filter (< 40) $ map (^3) [1..50]
```

Devuelve una lista cerrada.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Una forma que me parece bastante efectiva de entender este problema y otros similares es mediante **evaluación a mano**.  Escribimos las definiciones de las funciones que nos interesan, y usamos razonamiento estilo matemático (substitución de iguales) para ilustrar la respuesta.

Las funciones en cuestión son `filter` y `map`, las cuales podemos definir de este modo:

```
filter :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [a]
filter _ [] = []
filter p (a:as) = 
  let rest = filter p as in if p a then a : rest else rest

map :: (a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]
map _ [] = []
map f (a:as) = f a : map f as
```

Ahora tomemos la segunda expresión:

```
filter (<40) (map (^3) [1..50])  

  -- Forzamos la evaluación de la cabeza de `[1..50]` para 
  -- saber cuál ecuación de `map` debemos usar
  = filter (<40) (map (^3) (1:[2..50]))

  -- Segunda ecuación de `map`:
  = filter (<40) (1^3 : map (^3) [2..50])

  -- Segunda ecuación de `filter`:
  = let rest = filter (<40) (map (^3) [2..50])
    in if 1^3 < 40 then 1^3 : rest else rest

  -- Forzamos la evaluación de `1^3` para poder comparar el 
  -- resultado con `40`:
  = let rest = filter (<40) (map (^3) [2..50])
    in if 1 < 40 then 1 : rest else rest

  = let rest = filter (<40) (map (^3) [2..50])
    in if True then 1 : rest else rest

  -- `if True then x else y = x`, por lo tanto:
  = 1 : filter (<40) (map (^3) [2..50])

  .
  .
  .

  -- Cuando llegamos al final de la lista nos topamos con `[]`:
  = 1 : ... : filter (<40) (map (^3) [])

  -- Primera ecuación de `map`:
  = 1 : ... : filter (<40) []

  -- Primera ecuación de `filter`:
  = 1 : ... : []
```

Lo que hay que fijarse aquí es que esta evaluación la lista de resultado se "cierra" cuando se alcanza el constructor `[]` que "cierra" la lista `[1..50]`.  En el caso de `[1..]` no hay tal constructor `[]`.  Y si nos fijamos en las definiciones de `filter` y `map`, esto quiere decir que:

1. Las primeras ecuaciones de las respectivas definiciones nunca entran en juego cuando suplimos una lista infinita;
2. Estas primeras ecuaciones son las únicas que producen un `[]` que "cierra" el resultado;
3. Por lo tanto, `filter` y `map`, aplicadas a listas infinitas, siempre producen listas infinitas como resultado.

Comment: Muy buena explicación, gracias.

Answer (score 4):

Estás filtrando todos los elementos de una lista infinita, dicho filtro que no posee ninguna estructura interna (árbol, ordenación, etc...) y se se aplica a **todos los elementos** de la lista.

Una lista infinita como

```
[1..]
```

es una secuencia perezosa en la que los elementos sólo se evalúan cuando son requeridos, por ejemplo, al hacer (en interactivo)

```
> let xs = [1..]
> print 2
2
```

se ha definido `xs` pero nunca se hace referencia a ella, por lo que ninguno de los infinitos elementos de `xs` se ha tenido que evaluar.

Si hacemos

```
> let xs = [1..]
> print (xs!!3)
2
```

entonces se han tenido que evaluar los elementos `[0, 1, 2` para llegar al índice `2` solicitado.

**¿Cómo actúa `filter`?**

La función `filter` tiene la siguiente firma

```
filter :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [a]
```

y lo que hace es iterar **todos los elementos** de la lista de entrada y devolver sólo aquellos que cumplen la condición. Da igual si los elementos cumplen o no la condición, **tiene que recorrer todos los elementos**.

Por eso, el filtrado de una lista infinita produce una secuencia infinita de filtrados (que tomará un tiempo infinito obviamente).

Por ejemplo, el resultado de la siguiente expresión sabemos que es la lista vacía

```
filter (const False) [1..]
```

¡pero le estamos pidiendo que compruebe dicha función sobre los infinitos elementos de la lista!

Alternativas razonables a tu código serían

```
take 10 $ filter odd $ map (^3) [1..]
take 10 $ filter even $ map (^3) [1..]
takeWhile (<40) $ map (^3) [1..]
take 10 $ dropWhile (<40) $ map (^3) [1..]
```

etc...

Si deseas un resultado particular, deberás indicar explícitamente el problema a resolver.

Comment: Hola, las alternativas que propone no dan los mismos resultados. Sigo sin entender. Gracias de todas formas.

Comment: @RicardoAvilaLegrá ¿no dan los mismos resultados que qué cosa que se pide?, son sólo ejemplos. He extendido la explicación, espero quede más claro.

Comment: Lo he entendido ahora:

Comment: Creo que la cosa va así:   filter (< 40) $ map (^3) [1..]    no se ejecuta porque aunque se trata de una lista finita para nosotros, para haskell es una lista infinita ya que debe comprobar todos los elementos de una lista infinita. La lista definitiva se construye segun se vayan requierendo los valores por alguna otra funcion que los solicite ( digamos takeWhile) . Muchas gracias